# The Irregular at Magic High School episode 17 French rap credits

Tags: music, the-irregular-at-magic-high-school

I am trying to find the name / info on the French rap song played at 21:30 of "The Irregular at Magic High School" episode 17.

Does anyone know anything about it?
Is there a database that holds the music credits of anime?

I have googled everywhere and even shazam'd the song on my iPhone but did not find anything .

Any insight will be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of this song is **[Metaphore 2](https://youtu.be/8y9M6EEw7jE?t=2h8m55s)**.

It's found on the The Irregular at Magic High School [Original Soundtrack 2](http://vgmdb.net/album/46292) as song #20.

Comment: Ero, Hashirama, thanks a bunch.. this is the song i am looking for.  i will mark this answered.  but do you happen to know the credits, i.e. what group made that song?  Amazon.com has "Framemain Rockfeir" as the artist for the OST2 album.  i am not sure if he is also the artist for this particular song.

Comment: @FawziMasri I edit my answer for you.

Comment: @FawziMasri I have no idea who "Framemain Rockfeir" is, but there is no person of that name [credited on the album](http://vgmdb.net/db/covers.php?do=view&cover=211196). The vocalist for Metaphore 2 was IGOR (also the lyricist). The composer was Iwasaki Taku (same as the rest of the album).

Comment: @HashiramaSenju I removed the Amazon link you included because it is almost certainly illicit - full anime OSTs are almost never available for download on Amazon US, never mind singles. This "Framemain Rockfeirr" person seems to be some sort of scammer or something.